# How to convert ruby - Rspec to js test - opal gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, opalrb, opal

In my Ruby on Rails app I use [opal gem](https://github.com/opal/opal) for converting the ruby code to JS.
How can I convert also the Rspec tests to JS test - opal.
And how to run those JS/opal tests?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

I use the [hyper-spec](https://github.com/hyperstack-org/hyperstack/tree/edge/ruby/hyper-spec) gem.
It required:

- Use factory_bot gem instead of factory_girl gem.
- Add dummy rails app to rspec folder that use my gem.
- More configuration for the tests as describe in the readme.